# Voltage drop when switching FET

Tags: power, led, switching, fet

I am working on a project which will be switching LED strips with a max of 2A. 
As a test I have connected a 20W hallogen light. When I try to switch it I get a voltage drop as can be seen in the scope picture and causes my microcontroller to reboot (< 5V). I was thinking of using a capacitor to filter out the voltage drop.

How can I determine which value of capacitor I can use? Or does someone have any other tip I can do to fix this?

[image: Scope picture]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9msbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why have you chosen this circuit? With this circuit the voltage across the LED will never be 12 V but limited to 5 V - 1.4 V (Vbe of a Darlington transistor) = 3.6 V. Most of the energy from the supply is lost in the transistor. Your LED can **never** burn at full brightness (assuming it needs 12 V for that). You need to look up how to **properly** switch a 12 V LED from a 5 V PWM signal using an NPN. The LED needs to be at the collector side, not the emitter side as you have it now.

Comment: In addition to  Bimpelrekkie's point above, a halogen is a very poor substitute for LEDs. Halogens have a very low resistance when 'cold' and will initially draw substantially more current than their normal operating wattage rating would suggest. So as a result, your power supply is 'browning out'.

Comment: *I was thinking of using a capacitor to filter out the voltage drop.* Before thinking of a **solution** would it not be "better engineering" to find the **real cause** of the problem first? Do you realize that a 20 W halogen bulb has a **very different** behavior than an LED or even a resistor. Use a multimeter to measure the resistance of that bulb, do you expect it to be around 7 ohms (\$R=V^2/P\$)? But it measures much lower! That's because the filament will only be 7 ohms when it is glowing hot, when it is cold it has a much lower resistance. So more current flows..

Comment: ...and the supply might be unable to keep up. Resulting in a supply dip and a reset. You'd need a **VERY** big capacitor to fix that. Easier fix: get rid of the halogen lamp. Use an ordinary LED with a 1 k ohm resistor in series. That will tell you if your circuit works or not.

Comment: Why do you refer to a FET in your question text, but then have an NPN BJT in your schematic? Which is it?

Comment: What is providing your 12 V supply?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, about the hallogen light it is a good point. I will switch my setup to an LED setup. @Bimpelrekkie I know about this voltage drop. However when using a LED strip the loss is visual minimal. Further I could not really find a FET with the specs to drive these LED's don't know if you have any suggestion for it maybe?

Comment: To OP I believe what Bimpelrekkie is saying is that you have a fundamental wiring problem and that your transistor should be between the LED and ground rather than the LED being between transistor and ground as shown in your schematic.  Trivial to fix and no advantage to using the incorrect arrangement, so you may as well fix it.  If you want to confirm function at full current without actually setting up 2A worth of LEDs, a cheap high power resistor will do the job, perhaps 7 Ohm, 100W.  You would want a "non inductive" load.

Comment: @ArthurTimmermans Are you using a \$12\:\text{V}\$ supply to feed your microcontroller board, which has it's own \$5\:\text{V}\$ regulator, on board, to provide the supply for the microcontroller, itself? And is that the same \$12\:\text{V}\$ power supply that you want to also use for your \$2\:\text{A}\$ LED load? I see that there is some discussion here related to this question and I might make assumptions. But I'd rather just ask, instead. (Oh, and is the \$12\:\text{V}\$ supply from a "wall-wart" type of unit?)

Comment: @ArthurTimmermans  And you might also consider a [30 W, 6.8 ohm Ceramic Power Resistor](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074Z11BW9) as a temporary test load to verify the function of the circuit before attaching the LED system to it, or alternately to isolate problems with the circuit should you need to go into "debug mode" with some given circuit design/implementation. Resistors are simple devices. LED strips are far less so.

Comment: @jonk The 12V is split so 12V goes to the transistor circuit for the LED and it goes to a 7805 linear regulator to supply 5V for the microcontroller

Comment: @ArthurTimmermans Then it is the same \$12\:\text{V}\$ supply. Is this a wall-wart style? (The reason for the question has a LOT to do with the transformers and their "regulation," as used in some of these. So it is important to ask and answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to switch it I get a voltage drop as can be seen in the
>   scope picture and causes my microcontroller to reboot (< 5V). I was
>   thinking of using a capacitor to filter out the voltage drop.

Good idea!

Put a diode before the capacitor and then the lamp won't discharge the capacitor when it drags the supply voltage down. Like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGrpzv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this arrangement the capacitor only needs to be large enough to power the controller during supply voltage sags. Assuming the regulator needs 7V and the capacitor charges to 11.4V (12V - 0.6V across the diode), you have 4.4V of 'headroom' before the regulator starts to drop out. The formula for capacitor charge/discharge is t = C*V/I, so if the controller draws eg. 20mA then it should last 0.00047F * 4.4V / 0.02A = ~100ms.